# sizeof(text) not equal to : fp_len + 1

Tags: c

if

```
fp_len = ftell(fp);
```

prints **470**

shouldn't this be printing "**471**" ?  ( it prints **8**. probably first line only )

```
char *text = malloc(sizeof(*text) * fp_len + 1);
int text_len;
text_len = sizeof(text);

printf("text-len: %d --- ",text_len);
```

full:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(path, "r");

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

int fp_len;
fp_len = ftell(fp); 
printf("%d---", fp_len);

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

char *text = malloc(sizeof(*text) * fp_len + 1);

int text_len;
text_len = sizeof(text);
printf("text-len: %d --- ",text_len);

fread(text, fp_len, 1, fp);

printf("%s",text);

free(text);
```

Comment: Must be a duplicate, can't find one now. You take the size of a **pointer**.

Comment: `text_len = sizeof(text);` is the size of a `char` pointer, which on your system is 8, which is plausible.

Comment: It shouldn't print 471. `text` is a pointer which uses 4 or 8 bytes on most machines. You cannot use `sizeof` to query the amount of allocated memory from `malloc`

Comment: @Vanada: seems that your previous question got solved. How about accepting an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sizeof` is an operator in C and not a function. It acts on the type of the expression inside the brackets.

It tells the size of the type. In general cases when you do `sizeof` of say a char array like,

```
char array[] = "Hello";
sizeof(array);
```

you get 6, because the type of `array` is `char[6]`.

Now in this case you are doing `sizeof` on `text`.

`text` is defined as `char*` which is a pointer. Pointers on your system are 8 bytes. So it is giving out 8.

Trying to use `sizeof` which dynamically allocated buffers is not going to work. Instead you can use

```
sizeof(*text) * fp_len + 1
```

Because that is what you passed to `malloc`. That is ACTUALLY the size of the buffer pointed to by `text`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` gives the size of the type, not a string length.
In case of `char *text`, the type is a pointer value, and the size of a pointer value on a 64 bit machine is probably 8.